# git command warning says redirecting to <url>.git

Tags: git, gitlab, git-remote, git-fetch

I am holding a project on `gitlab`, and I am having a cloned copy on my `ubuntu` desktop. On recent days I am facing a weird warning (`redirecting to https://gitlab.com/<my_handle>/<project>.git/`) on `remote update` and `fetch` operation.

Below mentioned is my `remote`, do I need to update it to hold `.git` at the end of URL ?

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://gitlab.com/<my_handle>/<project> (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.com/<my_handle>/<project> (push)
```

Note: The other existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012504/what-does-the-warning-redirecting-to-actually-mean) does not answer this doubt.

Comment: The second answer at the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57507789/7976758

Comment: No. My doubt here is such warning does not come with other git servers. But why this warning is coming only for `gitlab` repos ?

Comment: Perhaps because Gitlab recently changed how they redirect from `repo` to `repo.git`.

Comment: Side note: *doubt* is not really synonymous with *question* in UK/US English. See https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2429/180540